# Reset position of React JS ball after 2 seconds timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I have a canvas that renders spheres with textures on them, which can be rotated by the user.
The spheres then stay at the last position rotated to, I want them to go back to the default position or a position i set. I've tried adding a timeout through javascript and useEffect but it didn't work.

This is the function that creates the spheres:

```
const Ball = (props) => {
  const [decal] = useTexture([props.imgUrl]);

  return (
    <Float speed={2.5} rotationIntensity={1} floatIntensity={2}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 0.05]} />
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow scale={2.75}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[1, 2]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color="#3d3d3d"
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-5}
          flatShading
        />
        <Decal
          position={[0, 0, 1]}
          rotation={[2 * Math.PI, 0, 6.25]}
          flatShading
          map={decal}
        />
      </mesh>
    </Float>
  );
};
```

What I tried was this (Ofcourse with imports and usage inside the previous function):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRotation([0, Math.PI / 4, 0]);
    const resetTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setRotation([0, 0, 0]);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(resetTimeout);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Maybe if you create a working codesandbox demo so it's easier for someone to help you with your problem.

Comment: @UmerAbbas It's live on https://souheil.netlify.app if that's what u mean.